# Code design question: "Document-level classes" in a document-based app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a document-based application, how can instances of "document level" classes be "aware" of the document they correspond to? Is this a case where one is forced to introduce coupling between classes? They say coupling is bad or should be minimized. What are your thoughts on this?

A bit more clarification: In a Core Data application, for example, to every document there corresponds a MOC. Let's say I want to have a special MocController that holds the MOC. Now, to repeat the question: How can an instance of this class be "aware" of which document it corresponds to? Am I forced to put an ivar in it that points to the NSWindowController (or some DocumentController) instance that controls the document? Or do there exist some better ways by which to avoid such coupling between these "document level" classes?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘document level’ classes? Maybe an example would help.

Comment: Thanks. I have now added more clarification to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am beginning to edge on the side that in this case, a coupling between all "document-level" objects and the "document-root" object, might not be too bad. In a way, it actually feels like a very natural coupling. Stuff like dependency injection may very well be overkill.

Using the example above, it seems natural that the WindowController (the "document-root" object, and the Owner of the document's NIB) should provide all the methods that the MocController (and other "document-level" objects, instantiated in the NIB) needs, and that the latter should contain an outlet to the former.

This is what I'm going with now. But I'll still wait for a day or two in case some more thoughts on this should arrive on the scene.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a prime case for [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): when you create one of these document-level objects, hand it a reference to the document (or whatever) it needs to know about.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about it. But do you happen to know what this phenomenon is called in Cocoa? I have the "Cocoa Design Patterns" book, but this pattern is not there. It could be called something else in the Cocoa world. Not sure.